# How to wake up Xubuntu 18.04 LTS pressing any key on keyboard?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, suspend, wakeup

Please guys, help me.

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 LTS in a Laptop DeLL Vostro Intel Core i3 2.1GHz 64 bits 4GB RAM.

But, when I suspend the PC, the system only wake up if I move a Bluetooth USB mouse connected to the laptop.

The laptop doesn't have a "wake up key". If the mouse isn't connected I can't wake up the computer.

Please, how to configure Xubuntu 18.04 LTS to wake up pressing a special combination of keys or pressing any key on keyboard?

Thank you!

Cristiano M.

Comment: It's either a BIOS option, or you can try to wake the computer by hitting the power key.

Comment: I can't help with your issue, but in QA-testing Xubuntu (& Lubuntu; currently 19.10) on many brands/models of hardware - some wake with keyboard, some require power buttons, and a smaller few can wake with a special key. This is all running a simple live or clean-install image, so it's hardware dependent in my opinion  (ie. I'd 2nd @heynnema's bios config option).